# Accessing indices from functions acting on entire arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want a function, `f`, that given an (n, 1) numpy array returns an (n, 1) numpy array where the values are those of the original plus their 0-axis index.

For example:

`f(np.array([[0],[0]])) = np.array([[0],[1]])`

`f(np.array([[4],[2],[3]])) = np.array([[4],[3],[5]])`

Is there some command, `cmd(x)`, that returns the index of the value the function is operating on? The code for `f` would look like:

```
def f(x):
    return x + cmd(x)
```

Comment: Do you want `+ np.arange(n).reshape(1, n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something that'll work no matter what the shape of `x`, you want something like:

`np.indices(x.shape)[0] + 1`

This can be optimized to build a smaller array if you're using a large array.